# What exactly means MS error code 0x800f0986?

Tags: windows-server-2019, windows-update

I cannot install update KB5009557 (Windows Server 2019, Version 1809, Build 17763.1339) as it fails with error code *0x800f0986*.

Both, online update and WSUS, are not successful.

I read several discussions about this error but first of all **I would like to understand the error code**. The only information I found is a [support article from Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/deployment/fix-windows-update-errors) where *0x800f0986* is described as

> 0x800f0986    PSFX_E_APPLY_FORWARD_DELTA_FAILED   Applying forward delta failed

I have no idea what *Applying forward delta failed* means.

So can anybody explain to me what error code 0x800f0986 actually stands for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This message should only apply to express updates, not full size updates.  It means that during the process of hydrating the partial file with forward deltas, it failed. Usually due to corruption or missing files.  A simple test may be to download and try to install the full file update.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/psfxwhitepaper

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "Usually due to corruption or missing files"? Are you talking about corrupted files on the target system or in the windows update package? And could you give me a hint where the "full file update" can be found? Thank you.

Comment: Files on the target system.  The full file update is here: https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB5009557

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately using the full file update I receive the same error (as shown in windows update log).

Comment: Are there any language packs installed?

Comment: `wmic os get muilanguages` shows a single entry "de-DE".