# Update of Windows Server 2019 fails with 0x800f0986

Tags: windows-server-2019, windows-update

This is a follow up to [What exactly means MS error code 0x800f0986?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1090747/what-exactly-means-ms-error-code-0x800f0986)

I use *Windows Server 2019 Standard*, Version 1809, Build 1339.

I am not able to perform any weekly updates as it fails with *0x800f0986*, both Online Update and WSUS fail.

When running `sfc /scannow` it complains about corrupted files which cannot be repaired.

Running `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` also fails. Running `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth  /Source:WIM:D:\sources\Install.wim:2 /limitaccess` by using a *Windows Server 2019 Evaluation* installer doesn't succeed either.

Finally, I tried to perform an *inplace reinstall* with a *Windows Server 2019 Evaluation* installer. But I cannot check the option to *keep all files and apps* as it complains that the installer contains a different version of the one installed ... which is not true as I have the Desktop Version installed and checked the *Windows Server 2019 Desktop Version* in the installer.

So, is there anything else I can do ...?